# Showing notification outside the render, in the function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

I'm new in react, I created a login page and I want to use notification for showing errors like wrong user/pass ... I created a component for notification this is my Notification component

```js
import React from 'react';
import Style from './notifications.css';
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';


class Notifications extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      top: -100,
      errorText: '',
    };
  }

  onShow = () => {

  }

  showNotification= () => {
    this.setState({
      top: 16,
    }, () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
          top: -100,
        });
      }, 3000);
    });
  }

  render(){
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
          <Container top={this.state.top}>{this.state.errorText}</Container>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Notifications;
```

I want to use this component in my app.js
and this is my app.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import Notifications from './Notifications/notifications';

showNatify = (errorText) => {
  <Notifications errorText={errorText} ></Notifications>

  submitFunAjax = () => {
    if (this.checkForSubmit() === true) {
      // Some Codes
    }

    Tools.Fetch(this, "Authentication.asmx/LoginToSystem", myParams, function (sender, response) {
      if (response[0] === "true") {
        //use my component for success
      }
      else if (response[0] === "false") {
        // use my component for danger
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [React Toastify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify) package. This is very easy to use and you can easily configure as you wish.

To install, Run:

> npm install --save react-toastify

Here is a simple demo of how you can use this.

```
 import React from 'react';
 
  import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
  import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
  
  function App(){
    const notify = () => toast("Wow so easy !");
 
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={notify}>Notify !</button>
        <ToastContainer />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Here is a [Live Demo](https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/introduction/).
Hope this helps!! Happy Coding!!